# i am using JNAT-PMPlib for Nat Traversal and i get pmp device null, pls help me to over come this errors?

Tags: java, android, nat, portforwarding

```
import com.hoodcomputing.natpmp.*;
import java.net.Inet4Address;

/**
 * This class provides an example that describes how this library is used.
 * @author flszen
 */
public class Example {
/**
 * This method demonstrates how to use the library to work with a NAT-PMP
 * gateway.
 */
public static void TestDevice() {
    NatPmpDevice pmpDevice = null;

    try {
        // To find the device, simply construct the class. An exception is
        // thrown if the device cannot be located or if the network is not
        // RFC1918.
        // When the device is constructed, you have to tell it whether you
        // want it to automatically shutdown with the JVM or if you'll take
        // the responsibility of shutting it down yourself. Refer to the
        // constructor documentation for the details. In this case, we'll
        // let it shut down with the JVM.
        pmpDevice = new NatPmpDevice(true);

        // The next step is always to determine the external address of
        // the device. This is done by constructing the request message
        // and enqueueing it.
        ExternalAddressRequestMessage extAddr = new ExternalAddressRequestMessage(null);
        pmpDevice.enqueueMessage(extAddr);

        // In this example, we want to purposefully wait until the queue is
        // empty. It is possible to receive notification when the operation
        // is complete. Refer to the documentation for the
        // ExternalAddressRequestMessage constructor.
        pmpDevice.waitUntilQueueEmpty();

        // We can try and get the external address to determine if the
        // gateway is functional.
        // This may throw an exception if there was an error receiving the
        // response. The method getResponseException() would also return an
        // exception object in this case, if you prefer avoiding using
        // try/catch for logic.
        Inet4Address extIP = extAddr.getExternalAddress();
```

Now, we can set up a port mapping. Refer to the javadoc for
     a gateway-selected available external port to the local port
 5000. The lifetime is 120 seconds. In implementation, you would
  want to consider having a longer lifetime and periodicly sending
   a MapRequestMessage to prevent it from expiring.
            MapRequestMessage map = new MapRequestMessage(true, 5000, 0, 120, null);
            pmpDevice.enqueueMessage(map);
            pmpDevice.waitUntilQueueEmpty();

```
        // Let's find out what the external port is.
        int extPort = map.getExternalPort();

        // All set!

        // Please refer to the javadoc if you run into trouble. As always,
        // contact a developer on the SourceForge project or post in the
        // forums if you have questions.
    } catch (NatPmpException ex) {
    }
}
```

}